# Tagging system in php

Tags: php, lucene, tagging

I want to impliment tagging system in my PHP project (same like Stackoverflow.com's tagging system). Can I use Lucene? If yes then how to use it in PHP.
Or is there any other jQuery plugin available? Please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question's pretty vague. Maybe if you explain your project, we could see where tagging fits in.

Comment: hey Tony thanks,
we have 1 module same like facebook timeline in project but want to include tagging system same like this site. Which will include all the information in our system & not only timelines info. There is huge amnt of data in multiple tables. So its quite hard to fetch it on runtime manually. So looking for plugin..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new field in your table named "tags" and when you search on your site
split the tags (lets say all the tags for each topic is separated by a ',') using *split* function in PHP with the character you used (in our case, comma (',')).

make a loop for each array of tags for each topic (nested loops) and search for a tag that is the same as you have searched.

hope i helped :)

Comment: You are right Naor.
But I want some intelesence following concept ex. if I inserted tag like "Colour" it should match all the phrases like "colours,coloured" etc.
can you suggest me any jquery plugin which will act as a generalized searching tool in system.

Comment: For Jquery generalized searching tool you could use Ajax and use Jquery to display the results.
You should add a _LIKE_ statement to your query (SQL), see:
[link](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php)
Sorry, I don't have any plugins for you to use.. I can help you build one though :)